# Skrollr.js как прижать последний блок к низу экрана?

Tags: javascript

Использую [плагин Skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), нужно фиксировать блок на несколько прокруток мыши(1-ый и 2-ой блок в примере), и потом снова имитировать обычный скролл(остальные блоки). 
Как сделать чтоб после последнего блока не было пустого пространства (последний блок 100vh)
Если средствами плагина нельзя сделать, то как сделать корректно на js? (типа когда последний блок доходит до верху нужно остановить весь wraper, а не просто зафиксировать последний блок)

```js
skrollr.init({});
// forceHeight: false
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.block-1 {
  background: #DEFCF9;
}

.block-2 {
  background: #CADEFC;
}

.block-3 {
  /* dinamic or fix height */
  height: 300px;
  background: #C3BEF0;
}

.block-4 {
  background: #CCA8E9;
  height: 232px;
}

.block-5 {
  background: #EF9037;
}

.block-3,
.block-4,
.block-5 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" data-0="top: 0%" data-500="" data-1000="top: -100%" data-1500="" data-2500="top: -400%">
  <div class="block block-1">
    <svg width="440" height="280">
      <path 
         data-0="stroke-dashoffset: 955"
         data-500="stroke-dashoffset: 0"
         stroke-dasharray="955"
         stroke="#000" fill="#DEFCF9" stroke-width="5" fill-opacity="0" d="m219.99999,72.7433c64.31804,-153.13809 316.31824,0 0,196.89184c-316.31824,-196.89184 -64.31804,-350.02992 0,-196.89184z" id="svg_4"/>
    </svg> this block 100 vh<br> STOP
  </div>
  <div class="block block-2">
    <div class="square" data-1000="transform: rotate(0deg)" data-1500="transform: rotate(360deg)"></div>
    this block 100 vh<br> STOP
  </div>
  <div class="block block-3">
    This block<br> is Dinamic or fix height<br>
  </div>
  <div class="block block-4">
    This block<br> is Dinamic or fix height also
  </div>
  <div class="block block-5">
    Last Block 100vh
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.11/skrollr.min.js"></script>
```